# Ajax add option to select for each json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to populate a select item with the values that I get from an ajax call, I return such values as a json array. With the code below, the select is created without any options.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/wp-content/gta/search_airport.php",
  data: {city: t_city}
}).done(function(resp){
  var sel = $('<select name="airport" id="slt">').appendTo('#pick_type');
  $.each(resp, function() {
$.each(this, function(k, v) {
$('<option>').val(k).text(v).appendTo('#slt');
   });
  });
});
```

Example json array

```
[{"name":"Los Angeles","code":"LAX"},{"name":"San Francisco","code":"SFO"}]
```

I would like the options to be something like `<option value="LAX">Los Angeles</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't needed a nested `$.each()`. Just loop through the array and directly access the properties of the object at each index:

```
$.each(resp, function(k, v) {
    $('<option>').val(v.code).text(v.name).appendTo('#slt');
});
```

On the first iteration, `v` will be `{"name":"Los Angeles","code":"LAX"}`, so `v.code` will be `"LAX"`. On the second iteration, `v` will be `{"name":"San Francisco","code":"SFO"}`, so `v.code` will be `"SFO"`...

(You may also need to add `dataType:"json"` to your `$.ajax()` options - if you don't specify jQuery tries to work it out from the response's MIME type.)

Comment: This does the job, thanks.. but then what happens with the `k` on the function?

Comment: `k` will be the index of the current item, so on first iteration it will be `0`, then second iteration it will be `1`. For your particular requirement you don't need to use `k` for anything within your function, but it _does_ need to be in the function declaration as a placeholder so that `v` is the _second_ argument. Although now that I think about it you could leave out `k` and `v` and use `this.code` and `this.name` within the function...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/wp-content/gta/search_airport.php",
    data: {city: t_city},
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(resp) {
    var sel = $('<select name="airport" id="slt">').appendTo('#pick_type');
    $.each(resp, function(key,val) {
        $.each(val, function(k, v) {
            $('<option>').val(k).text(v).appendTo('#slt');
        });
    });
});
```